# RAM doesn't increase to normal value after downloading a file

Tags: c#, binary, download

I made a server and client (As training). They both communicate perfect. The only problem that appears comes when Iam uploading a file to my server from my client. When the server is downloading my servers-RAM goes up around 860MB (--> Downloading a 299MByte file). I noticed that everytime a client has finished uploading my RAM doesnt go back to normal value. Instead it is adding to the current ram value of my server (2 clients finished uploading --> server ram goes over 1300MB)

**Here is my Code from my server where it is reciving the file**

```
private void DownloadFileFromClient(string path, string nameAndExtension, TcpClient client)
    {


        string currFileName = "Download";
        string savingPath = path;

        if (File.Exists(savingPath)) //Wenn der Pfad einen Namen für die Datei enthält
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(savingPath);
            currFileName = fi.Name;
        }
        else if (Directory.Exists(savingPath)) //Wenn der Pfad zu einem Ordner führt 
        {
            int counter = 0; //zählt die doppelten Datein nachoben
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(savingPath))
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
                string[] name = fi.Name.ToString().Split('.');
                if (name[0].ToUpperInvariant() == currFileName.ToUpperInvariant()) //Wenn schon eine Datei mit dem selben Namen vorhanden ist
                {
                    counter++;
                    currFileName = "download" + counter.ToString();
                }

            }

            savingPath = savingPath + "\\" + currFileName + "." + nameAndExtension;
        }


        using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            object op;
            op = bf.Deserialize(stream); // Deserialize the Object from Stream

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream);
            byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(MaxDownloadBytes); //Maximale Dateiengröße in Bytes 10MB = 10485760Bytes | 50MB = 52428800Bytes | 100MB = 104857600Bytes | 500MB = 524288000Bytes
            br.Dispose();
            br.Close();

            using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(savingPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                filestream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
        }
        LogMessage("Succefully downloaded file from Client", client.GetHashCode().ToString(), "Manuel", "test", client);


    }
```

I tryied to dispose all, but it didnt help alot. Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Use a profiler and joyfully inspect your heap.  With such a tool, you can identify leaks extremely quickly.

Comment: is the joyfully part a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it...almost. I just added `GC.Collect();` after filestream gets closed.

(codesource from TyCobb, thanks)

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(MaxDownloadBytes);

         using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(savingPath, FileMode.CreateNew,  FileAccess.Write))
         {
            filestream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         }

         GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

But somehow after the 299MB Download the RAM is up to 300MB, but doesnt change if iam downloading another file.

Comment: If all it was, was a GC.Collect then there is nothing wrong and the system will free up the memory when it needs it. There's no reason to call GC.Collect. You should still look into chunking so it doesn't even take up that much memory to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't necessarily see anything wrong, but there could be some weirdness with all of the streams and reading you have going on that aren't necessarily useful. Below is a tweak to what you have to remove what appears to be unnecessary code / stream reading.

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        byte[] buffer = br.ReadBytes(MaxDownloadBytes);

        using (FileStream filestream = new FileStream(savingPath, FileMode.CreateNew,  FileAccess.Write))
        {
            filestream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

I would highly recommend doing this in chunks. Doing that will allow you to remove the necessity for `BinaryReader`. [You can see an example of what just using the `NetworkStream` looks like here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read.aspx). It would also make your download consume much less memory because you aren't downloading the entire file into memory before you write it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I`ll test it on tuesday.

Comment: It stil doesnt work. And I dont know how to solve it yet